# “For the sake of your ḥesed” in the Psalms

Tags: hebrew, psalms

Psalm 6:5[4]:<sup>1</sup>

> ‏שׁוּבָה יְהוָה חַלְּצָה נַפְשִׁ֑י הוֹשִׁיעֵנִי **לְמַעַן** חַסְדֶּֽךָ׃  <sub>(BHS)</sub>
>
> Turn, LORD, and deliver me;
>         save me **because of** your unfailing love. <sub>(NIV)</sub>
>
> Turn, O LORD, deliver my life;
>        save me **for the sake of** your steadfast love. <sub>(ESV)</sub>

In my basically English<sup>2</sup>  way of thinking, these are very different.

- because of = on account of = due to; i.e. introducing **the cause**
- for the sake of = for the benefit of (noun)  | in order to (verb)  = (by extension) in order to demonstrate (noun); i.e. introducing **the effect**

The latter is how the common phrase לְמַעַן שְׁמוֹ “for his name’s sake” seems to be generally understood and translated (including NIV), but “because” is also a well-attested meaning of לְמַעַן. “Because” makes a little more sense to me in the immediate context of Psalm 6:5[4], his *ḥesed* (≈"steadfast love”) being cited as a motivation for the act of saving. On the other hand, I suppose the ESV rendering means something like “in order to demonstrate your *ḥesed*”, which is also conceivable and would be consistent with the sense of the “for your name’s sake” refrain.<sup>3</sup>

Is the intended meaning that God’s *ḥesed* will motivate him to deliver or that he will deliver in order to demonstrate his *ḥesed*? Or am I the only one who feels like those are different?

---

<sub>1. Basically the same issue applies in 44:27[26], with פדה for ישע.</sub>


<sub>2. And this is most likely the problem.</sub>


<sub>3. It’s also possible that I don’t understand what “for your name’s sake” means. For the most part in the Psalms it seems possible to construe it either way (*due to the nature of your name=character* | *in order to demonstrate/advance your name=reputation/glory*). There are a bunch of these in Ezekiel, Jeremiah, and Isaiah (mostly "... *my* name") that are also very confusing to me.</sub>

Comment: [למען] is a spectrum of meaning whose median does not meet with the median of "for sake of". First you need to understand  [ען] or  [לען], and then, the intensive [מען], which leads to its subsequent infinitive  [למען]. Otherwise you'd be like trying to understand the word [אשר], as though it is assured a 1-1 mapping to the English conjunctive relative adjective. Without even understanding the root meaning of  [אשר].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case it's not possible to decide between the two meanings.

By way of comparison, take a look at 1 Kings 11:12.

> אַךְ־בְּיָמֶ֙יךָ֙ לֹ֣א אֶעֱשֶׂ֔נָּה **לְמַ֖עַן דָּוִ֣ד אָבִ֑יךָ** מִיַּ֥ד בִּנְךָ֖ אֶקְרָעֶֽנָּה׃

NIV:

> But, **for the sake of your father David**, I will not do it in your lifetime; I will tear it away from your son.

Does this mean, “because of what a great guy David was”, or “so that I don't destroy David's reputation”? Both are fair readings of what I would propose as the most neutral translation, “because of David”.

Back to Psalm 6, I think it's similarly not possible to decide whether the intention behind “because of your love” means “because of what your covenant love [or whatever] requires” and “for the sake of the reputation of your covenant love”.

Certainly a reading where the love motivates the action is possible. In Psalm 69:18 we have:

> קָרְבָ֣ה אֶל־נַפְשִׁ֣י גְאָלָ֑הּ לְמַ֖עַן אֹיְבַ֣י פְּדֵֽנִי׃

NET:

> Come near me and redeem me! Because of my enemies, rescue me!

That's clearly “because of my enemies” and not “for the sake of the enemies.” But I think it would be quite a stretch to say that that is the only possible meaning of לְמַ֖עַן .

Comment: Perhaps in English we can use "considering", which covers both these aspects: "considering your father David, I will not do it" and "considering my enemies, rescue me". It isn't very readable though.